# Making an img switch source with a 200ms crossfade using jQuery animate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, image, fade, src

Here's my relevant code, I'm switch the image according to where I click. Is there some way for me to gradually switch the images? Maybe animate them while switching? A sort of fade in fade out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { //fire on DOM ready
        $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
            defaultpower: 2,
            powerrange: [2, 5],
            largeimage: null,
            magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
        })

        $('#smallpictureone').click(function () {
            $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));

            $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
                defaultpower: 2,
                powerrange: [2, 5],
                largeimage: null,
                magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
            })
        });

        $('#smallpicturetwo').click(function () {
            $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));

            $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
                defaultpower: 2,
                powerrange: [2, 5],
                largeimage: null,
                magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
            })
        });

        $('#smallpicturethree').click(function () {
            $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));

            $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
                defaultpower: 2,
                powerrange: [2, 5],
                largeimage: null,
                magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
            })
        });

        $('#smallpicturefour').click(function () {
            $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));

            $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
                defaultpower: 2,
                powerrange: [2, 5],
                largeimage: null,
                magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
            })
        });

        $('#smallpicturefive').click(function () {
            $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));

            $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
                defaultpower: 2,
                powerrange: [2, 5],
                largeimage: null,
                magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have another *related* question about my javascript code. I'm using a Javascript library I found online that allows me to zoom the image around very nicely. However, when I switch the src to another image, the zoom remain on the first. So I'm 're-hooking' the library to the image each click I make. **Does this have a negatie performance hit I'm not aware of? Will a current gen correctly clean up after me?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because I'm a stickler; You can super-simplify your JS code by reducing your code repetition by using a better selector. You can chain selectors by using a comma to separate them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { //fire on DOM ready
    $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
        defaultpower: 2,
        powerrange: [2, 5],
        largeimage: null,
        magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
    })

    $('#smallpictureone, #smallpicturetwo, #smallpicturethree, #smallpicturefour, #smallpicturefive').click(function () {
        $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));

        $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom({
            defaultpower: 2,
            powerrange: [2, 5],
            largeimage: null,
            magnifiersize: [200, 200] //<--no comma following last option!
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

But you could do even better by not targeting those ids at all and using a class instead. eg:

```
$('.smallpicture').click(function(){ /* ... */ });
```

You can also reduce your repetition by declaring your "addpowerzoom" options beforehand and reusing the variable reference. eg:

```
var powerZoomOpts = {
  defaultpower: 2,
  powerrange: [2, 5],
  largeimage: null,
  magnifiersize: [200, 200]
};
```

Then in your call to initialize the power zoom plugin:

```
 $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom(powerZoomOpts);
```

But wait! There's more. You can also chain the powerzoom onto the `attr()` call on the line before that. eg:

```
$("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $(this).attr("src")).addpowerzoom(powerZoomOpts);
```

For a final result of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { //fire on DOM ready
    var powerZoomOpts = {
        defaultpower: 2,
        powerrange: [2, 5],
        largeimage: null,
        magnifiersize: [200, 200]
    };

    $('#mainproductpicture').addpowerzoom(powerZoomOpts);

    $('.smallpicture').click(function () {
        $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $(this).attr("src")).addpowerzoom(powerZoomOpts);
    });
});
</script>
```

Doesn't that look so much better?

In order to cross-fade (as others have stated) You must have two `img` elements. One positioned overtop the other. The bottom image should start off being hidden from view by the image on top. It won't yet have a `src` attribute.

The second step is to change the `src` of the bottom `img` to be the image you want to crossfade to. Then you `.fadeOut(200)` the top image. Use a callback function to change the top image's `src` attribute to the bottom image's `src` attribute so as to 'prime' the set of images for the next crossfade.

Here's an example:

```
var $topimg = $('#topimage');
var $bottomimg = $('#bottomimage'); /* cache $topimg & $bottomimg jQuery objects for later use */

$('.fadeable-images').click(function(e){
  $bottomimg.attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
  $topimg.fadeOut(200, function(){
    $topimg.attr('src', $bottomimg.attr('src')).show();
  });
});
```

The rest is CSS to align the two image tags in the appropriate positions.

Comment: Thank so much for taking the time to write this up. :) I originally used IDs because I wasn't aware of the $(this) selector, this should really clean up my code. Thank you.

Comment: @Sergio I just added an actual answer in the body of my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot animate the `src` attribute (I can't believe I just wrote that). If you want your images to crossfade, you have to put them one on top of the other, and animate the opacity of the top one.

As for your "re-hooking" having a negative performance hit: No. This is the way Javascript is supposed to be used.

Comment: I thumbed this up only because you cannot animate the src attribute. Generally you can only animate things that are numeric. Though there's a plugin to let you animate hex colors. The reason I'm commenting is because there IS a negative performance hit for calling the jQuery constructor (`$`) more than necessary.

Comment: @sholsinger: note that he did not ask about the selector. That can easily be cached: `var mainproductpicture = $('#mainproductpicture');`. He specifically asked about "re-hooking" his zoomer on the element.

Comment: True, but the way in which he was doing it he was adding some latency to the execution of the script. And I would recommend that any cached jQuery objects (`var $foo = $('#foo')`) start with a `$` so that you know just by looking at it that it is a jQuery instance.

Comment: @sholsinger: Spot on! In my own code, all my jQuery object's variable names start with a `$`. However, I'm not going to force my coding style onto anyone else ;)